# Laravel restore back deleted record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to implement the queue that system will be restored back a deleted record. Now my code is working without error but the record will not restore back after deleted.

```
public function delete_invoice($job, $data)
    {
        Debugbar::info("invoiceSale");
        try {
            return DB::transaction(function ()use ($job,$data) {

            });
        } catch (TransactionException $e) {
            # reestore function
            extract($data);
            $data = $Class::withTrashed()->find($id);
            $data->restore();
            Debugbar::info($data->toArray());
            return Response::json(['errors' => array_flatten($e->getErrors())], 400);
        }
    }
```

This is the function from controller

```
public function destroy($id, $message = '')
{
    Debugbar::info("ok");
    Queue::push('IQueue@delete_invoice', [
        'id' => $id,
        'Class' => $this->Class,

    ]);

    return parent::destroy($id, trans("$this->class.invoice")); <--delete invoice
}
```

Comment: **Warning:** I hope that you have 100% control of the contents in `$data` since you're using `extract()` (specially with the default flags).

Comment: Is there any example or documentation about `extract()` for Laravel 4.2? I'm not sure whether I have 100% control the content.

Comment: `extract()` is a core PHP function and has nothing to do with Laravel. That function should never be used on data you're not 100% in control over (you've created it) and even then it can cause side effects if you're not careful. Just access the data like this: `$data['id']` instead. No need to use that function in this context. [Here's the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Comment: Actually, I use the `extract()` function to delete my others data in `try` without any issue.

Comment: i don't think you understand the issue with `extract()`. If you don't have 100% control and the there is a `$data['foo']` in your array and you have a variable `$foo` defined before the extract(), it will overwrite your defined `$foo` variable with the value in the `$data`-array. [Read the warnings in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Comment: Use Soft Deleting it should work - [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following code hope it will help you.

```
public function destroy(Trip $trip)
{
    $trip->delete();
    flash()->warning('Trip '.$trip->id.' successfully deleted! <a href=trips/'.$trip->id.'/restore>UNDO</a>');
    return redirect('trips');
}

public function restore(Request $request) 
{
    $trip = Trip::withTrashed()->where('id', $request['id'])->restore();
    return redirect ('trips');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your code deletes the record somewhere else and the code you presented here is supposed to restore that record, based on the model class and record id passed via the `$data` array as `['Class' => ..., 'id' => ...]`.

Then what is your transaction meant to do? Is there any code you did not paste in? Otherwise catch is never called as there is no exception thrown and hence you code is not executed.

So just remove the try and catch.

Comment: The transaction also will do the delete action but I did the validation, it will go to catch if something went wrong. Therefore, the code always will go to catch because I already let it always fault for testing purpose.

Comment: In that case I'd verify whether $data contains 'Class' and 'id' as you expect. Furthermore: do you use the [SoftDeletingTrait](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#soft-deleting) on your model?

Comment: Your controller's `$this->Class` property may not return your model's class (Invoice I guess).

Comment: Yeah...I already use `SoftDeletingTrait`. I found that `restore` function was executed then return to the `destroy` function but the end of `destroy` function always deletes the data again.